# How to manipulate combobox by another combobox in C# depending on item selection

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, combobox

I have two tables in my database and they are company and delegate and in my bill form I have two comboboxes, one for displaying the companies and the other for displaying the delegates ...

Now when I select a company in the first combobox, the second combobox of delegates should display the delegates related to the selected company. The `Company` table has the primary key `compId` and the `Delegate` table has a foreign key `compId` ...

I tried to code it like these but it doesn't give me the required result it just display all delegates ... any help!

```
public PBillFrm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    da = new SqlDataAdapter("select compId, compName from company", cn);
    da.Fill(dt);

    PBillCompNamecmbo.DataSource = dt;
    PBillCompNamecmbo.DisplayMember = "compName";
    PBillCompNamecmbo.ValueMember = "compId";

    da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select delId,delName from delegate where compId=" + PBillCompNamecmbo.ValueMember + "", cn);
    da2.Fill(dt2);

    pBillDelNamecmbo.DataSource = dt2;
    pBillDelNamecmbo.DisplayMember = "delName";
    pBillDelNamecmbo.ValueMember = "delId";                     
}
```

Comment: Start from here: `where compId=" + PBillCompNamecmbo.ValueMember` actually expands to `where compId=compId`, which is always `true` and does not apply any filtering. You should bind a parameter containing the desired `compId` value instead.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

Tip 1:
Set AutoPostBack Property of `PBillCompNamecmbo` to "**TRUE**"

Tip 2:
Move the following code to `OnChangeFunction` of `PBillCompNamecmbo`

```
da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select delId,delName from delegate where compId=@Id", cn);
da2.Fill(dt2);
pBillDelNamecmbo.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Convert.ToInt32(PBillCompNamecmbo.ValueMember));
pBillDelNamecmbo.DataSource = dt2;
pBillDelNamecmbo.DisplayMember = "delName";
pBillDelNamecmbo.ValueMember = "delId";
```

Comment: I think OP is using WinForms not WebForms.